# Understand how to compute sum at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I have this piece of code and want to understand:

```
template <unsigned...>
struct sum;

template<unsigned size>
struct sum<size>
{
    enum {value = size};
};

template<unsigned size, unsigned... sizes>
struct sum<size, sizes...>
{
    enum { value = size + sum<sizes...>::value }; 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sum<1, 2>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the unimplemented sum(that takes unsigned... just as last struct specialization, isn't there a conflict?) must be present at all and how one can specialize sum using same parameters from template part (`e.g. sum<size, sizes...>` same as `template <unsigned size, sizes...>`.
Why the bellow just doesn't work ?

```
template<unsigned size>
struct sum
{
    enum {value = size};
};

template<unsigned size, unsigned... sizes>
struct sum
{
    enum { value = size + sum<sizes...>::value; }; 
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that the syntax is a bit different.  When you declare the primary template:

```
template <unsigned...>
struct sum;
```

You don't give the template parameters after `sum`.  This is because you are creating a brand new template, and saying that it takes an arbitrary number of unsigned integers as parameters.

When you are doing this:

```
template<unsigned size, unsigned... sizes>
struct sum<size, sizes...>
{
    enum { value = size + sum<sizes...>::value }; 
};
```

you are specializing the template that you declared before.  You are saying that in the case where your parameters consist of an unsigned value followed by an arbitrary number of other unsigned values, use this definition.  This isn't exactly the same as the primary template.  The primary template includes the possibility of having zero parameters.

When you try to do this:

```
template<unsigned size>
struct sum
{
    enum { value = size };
};

template<unsigned size, unsigned... sizes>
struct sum // OOPS! A template called `sum` has already been declared!
{
    enum { value = size + sum<sizes...>::value }; 
};
```

you are trying to make two different class templates with the same name, which isn't allowed.

Note that this is a bit different from how function templates work.  With function templates, you can do overloading, so having multiple function templates with the same name is fine.  However with function templates, you can't do partial specialization, since this would create a lot of ambiguity.

You might think that there is ambiguity between the primary template and the specializations, but more-specialized specializations always take precedence over less-specialized specializations, and the primary template can always be considered the least specialized.  If this wasn't true, then partial specialization wouldn't work at all.

Comment: yes, I understand now, about the naming part. But how does it come that the first unimplemented sum does not colide(ambigous) with the last one ? When user calls sum<1, 2> it should match both the unimplemented and the last specialization

Comment: @Gmt: That's true, but the specializations take precedence.  I've added a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration:

```
template<unsigned int... Ns>
struct sum;
```

is a forward declaration: It declares the template as a template with a variable number of `unsigned int` parameters.

The first specialization is the base case of the metafunction, which holds the case where the variadic-pack have one parameter only:

```
template<unsigned size>
struct sum<size>
{
    enum {value = size};
};
```

The second specialization is the recursive case: It holds the case when the variadic-pack has at least one parameter:

```
template<unsigned size, unsigned... sizes>
struct sum<size, sizes...>
{
    enum { value = size + sum<sizes...>::value }; 
};
```

I suggest you to learn more about C++ template mechanisms (like instantation, template specialization, etc) before to write/learn template-meta-programming.

Comment: A *forward declaration* is just a *declaration*. Nothing special about it, so why emphasize it? If anything, *emphasize* it is a **primary *class template* declaration**.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm trying to empasize that the forward declaration could be viewed as the *declaration* of the metafunction, and the specializations are the cases of the recursive metafunction.

Answer (score 0):

With the new features of c++20, you could solve the problem like this:

- Initialize the `struct` with many arguments:

  ```cpp
  template<int ...args>
  ```
- Your result will be the `const auto`.

  ```cpp
  static const auto value = (0 + ... + args);
  ```
- `auto` keyword is defined in c++17, able to deduce the function's return type.

Code:

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<int ...args>
struct sum
{
    static const auto value = (0 + ... + args);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    const auto res = sum<10, 20, 40, -5>();
    std::cout << "Result ";
    std::cout << res.value;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```sh
Result 65
```